# Web request monitoring for .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis-7, monitoring

### Problem Background

I have few web applications which were developed using Microsoft .net framework 4.0 and running on the IIS 7.0 .so now i need to track traffic information(requested user,ip,application name ,address,request time etc..) for all these application and persist into a database or text file etc.

while i was searching on this i found HTTP handlers concept.

Is this handy to use my case ? or are there any alternatives which can fulfill my requirement?

**I need to write this component as plug-abbe one.because i need connect this component easily to another web application also.**

appreciate your ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `HttpModule` to intercept all requests via the `BeginRequest` event, like this:

```
public class RequestLoggingModule : IHttpModule
{
    private HttpApplication httpApp;

    public void Init(HttpApplication httpApp)
    {
        this.httpApp = httpApp;
        httpApp.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(OnBeginRequest);
    }

    void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the user that made the request
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpResponse response = application.Context.Response;

        WindowsIdentity identity = 
           (WindowsIdentity)application.Context.User.Identity;

        LogInformation(identity.Name);

        // Do this for other information you want to log here

    }

    private void LogInformation(string data)
    {
        EventLog log = new EventLog();
        log.Source = "Application XYZ Request Logging";
        log.WriteEntry(data, EventLogEntryType.Information);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: :first Thanks for your solution.By the way i have one more question. can i plug this component to the any asp .net web application without **code changes** to the web application. :)

Comment: @Renushi - yes, as long as the mechanism for retrieving the data is the same, that is if the logic for retrieving the logged on user varies between applications then you may need to build a separate HTTP module for each variation or permutation to cover all the bases. But generally speaking, this should work across applications.